# Java 8 DateTimeFormatterBuilder appendValue zeroPadding Not working as expected

Tags: date, java-8, dateformatter

I am trying to format the milliseconds to 3 digit on serialize to ISOString from offsetDate Time

| Value | Expected | Actual |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-06-16T05:47:40.1-06:00 | 2020-06-16T11:47:40.001Z | 2020-06-16T11:47:40.100Z |
| 2020-06-16T05:47:40.12-06:00 | 020-06-16T11:47:40.012Z | 020-06-16T11:47:40.120Z |

When I used

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter outFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .parseLenient()
        .append(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"))
        .appendLiteral('.')
        .appendValue(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND,3)
        .appendZoneId()
        .toFormatter()
        .withZone(ZoneId.from(ZoneOffset.UTC));
```

The documentation says padding will be on Left. But I am getting padding on right.

Any suggestion on how to achieve with date Formatter?

Comment: Why do you expect 0.1 sec (100 msec) to be represented as 0.001 sec (1 msec)?

Comment: 2020-06-16T05:47:40.1-06:00.There is 40sec after that there is 1 on fraction. Some of our code uses @JsonFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss:SSSXXX") jackson annotation which converts to 001ms. I am trying to unify many format to output with millis. so which one is right? should I consider that as 40.1 sec instead 40sec 1millisec?

Comment: From the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30087963/parsing-milliseconds-fraction-of-date-in-java . I understood its fraction and i should change my expectation. Thanks a lot. Though @jsonFormat with simpleDate pattern SSS consider that as milliseconds in Java8 time packege SSS is fraction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.1` in `2020-06-16T05:47:40.1-06:00` represents the [fraction-of-second](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) i.e. `.1` second and thus, can be also written as `.100` second. In terms of millisecond, it will be `.1 * 1000` = `100` milliseconds.

Apart from this, you can simplify your code greatly by using  [`OffsetDateTime#withOffsetSameInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#withOffsetSameInstant-java.time.ZoneOffset-), as shown below:

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(parseOdtStrAndConvertWithOffsetSameInstant("2020-06-16T05:47:40.1-06:00"));
        System.out.println(parseOdtStrAndConvertWithOffsetSameInstant("2020-06-16T05:47:40.12-06:00"));
    }

    static String parseOdtStrAndConvertWithOffsetSameInstant(String text) {
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(text).withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
        return odt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX"));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-06-16T11:47:40.100Z
2020-06-16T11:47:40.120Z
```

Comment: I believe that `.toString()` will not give the desired string in the corner case where the fraction of second happens to be 0. Then the millis would be left out. Consider a `DateTimeFormatter` built from a pattern including `.SSS` for three decimals.

Comment: Thanks, @OleV.V. for the valuable suggestion. Just for future visitors: this may happen even when the second is `0` (e.g. `2020-06-16T05:47-06:00`) because of the way `java.time.Time#toString` has been implemented. I've updated the code to return the formatted `OffsetDateTime` string.